# Recursively find item in array and splice out found item from the reference array

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, tree, javascript-objects

I'm trying to find item in an array of objects recursively and then rebuild the same array but without the found item in it. When the item is found I'd like to splice it out from the reference array. Below is my attempt, but unfortunately it's not working at all.

```js
var tt = [{ age : 4, els : [{ age : 12, els : [] },{ age : 32, els : [{ age :44, els :[] },{ age : 100, els : [ { age: 3, els : [], age : 22, els : [{ age : 13, els : []},{ age : 99, els : []},{ age : 88, els : [{ age : 16, els : [] }]}] } ] }] }] },{ age: 223, els : [] },{ age : 120, els : [{ age :300, els : [] },{ age :301, els : [{ age : 400, els : [] }] }] }];

kk = [];

var test = function(els){
 for( var i = 0; i < els.length; i++ ){
   if( els[i].age == 400 ){
     console.log('found');
     console.log(els[i]);
     return;
   }else{
    kk.push(els[i]);
    test(els[i].els);
   }
 }
}

console.log( tt ) // -- show original array
console.log( test(tt) ); // -- show found item
console.log( kk ); // -- show new array without the newly found item
```

Comment: Having the function mutate a hardcoded `kk` is not a good idea--if you want the function to retrieve the matched element and produce a filtered version, my advice is to return a pair of values as an object. I recommend modifying your design or [explaining why you need to follow such an unusual requirement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Beyond this, what happens to children when the element matching the predicate is removed? What should be done when multiple elements match the predicate?

Comment: Also, when you say "splice", that suggests that you want to mutate the original. Is this the intent or do you want a totally fresh copy? If you're mutating, seems like there's no benefit in returning a copy so the requirements seem a bit contradictory. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @ggorlen simply my objective is to find an item and remove it from the array.

Comment: OK, gotcha. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While the goal is noble, I don't think the proposed design is a sound choice. There are a few violations here:

- [Encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) is broken. By [hardcoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding) `test` to only populate a global with the specific name `kk`, we've needlessly tied the function down to a single context, rendering it unreusable.
- By returning a value and producing a [side effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)), the `test` function becomes difficult to reason about.
- There's no reason not to make the child key and target removal value parameters so to generalize `test` (let's call the function `filterRecursive`). Like [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), this function should work with an arbitrary callback predicate.
- These variable names are not very descriptive choices, but I'm assuming that's just for the purposes of the question.

Here's a suggestion on how you might approach this. I'm returning an object that contains `result` and `removed` keys (I'm not crazy about [returning two values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), but it's better than a side effect) which allow you to access the updated structure as well as a flattened list of all the removed objects that failed the predicate. The original array is not mutated.

```js
const data = [
  {
    age: 1,
    els: [{
      age: 2,
      els: []
    }, {
      age: 3,
      els: [{
        age: 4,
        els: []
      }, {
        age: 5,
        els: []
      }]
    }]
  },
  {
    age: 6,
    els: []
  }
];


const filterRecursive = (arr, predicate, childKey, removed=[]) => {
  removed.push(...arr.filter(e => !predicate(e)));  
  const result = arr.filter(predicate).map(e => {
    if (e[childKey]) {
      const {result: sub} = filterRecursive(e[childKey], predicate, childKey, removed);
      return {...e, [childKey]: sub};
    }
    
    return e;
  });

  return {result: result, removed: removed};
};

const {result, removed} = filterRecursive(data, e => ![4, 6].includes(e.age), "els");
console.log("original", data);
console.log("result", result);
console.log("removed", removed);
```

Here's a run on your original structure and predicate:

```js
const filterRecursive = (arr, predicate, childKey, removed=[]) => {
  removed.push(...arr.filter(e => !predicate(e)));  
  const result = arr.filter(predicate).map(e => {
    if (e[childKey]) {
      const {result: sub} = filterRecursive(e[childKey], predicate, childKey, removed);
      return {...e, [childKey]: sub};
    }

    return e;
  });

  return {result: result, removed: removed};
};

const data = [{ age : 4, els : [{ age : 12, els : [] },{ age : 32, els : [{ age :44, els :[] },{ age : 100, els : [ { age: 3, els : [], age : 22, els : [{ age : 13, els : []},{ age : 99, els : []},{ age : 88, els : [{ age : 16, els : [] }]}] } ] }] }] },{ age: 223, els : [] },{ age : 120, els : [{ age :300, els : [] },{ age :301, els : [{ age : 400, els : [] }] }] }];
console.log(filterRecursive(data, e => e.age !== 400, "els"));
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because in the `for` loop in your `test()` , there is a return, which will break the loop but return nothing. you should `return` out of the for-loop

And because you have a recursive calling with `test()`, much better you define another array to keep the items you found, then `console.log` it

```js
var tt = [{ age : 4, els : [{ age : 12, els : [] },{ age : 32, els : [{ age :44, els :[] },{ age : 100, els : [ { age: 3, els : [], age : 22, els : [{ age : 13, els : []},{ age : 99, els : []},{ age : 88, els : [{ age : 16, els : [] }]}] } ] }] }] },{ age: 223, els : [] },{ age : 120, els : [{ age :300, els : [] },{ age :301, els : [{ age : 400, els : [] }] }] }];

var kk = [];
var mm = [];

var test = function(els){
 for( var i = 0; i < els.length; i++ ){
   if( els[i].age == 400 ){
     console.log('found');
     console.log(els[i]);
     mm.push(els[i])
   }else{
    kk.push(els[i]);
    test(els[i].els);
   }
 }
 // return at here, not in the for-loop
 return mm;
}

console.log( tt ) // -- show original array
console.log( test(tt), mm ); // -- show found item
console.log( kk ); // -- show new array without the newly found item
```

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting example.
Below is my code.

```
var tt = [{ age: 4, els: [{ age: 12, els: [] }, { age: 400, els: [{ age: 44, els: [] }, { age: 100, els: [{ age: 3, els: [], age: 22, els: [{ age: 13, els: [] }, { age: 99, els: [] }, { age: 88, els: [{ age: 16, els: [] }] }] }] }] }] }, { age: 223, els: [] }, { age: 120, els: [{ age: 300, els: [] }, { age: 301, els: [{ age: 400, els: [] }] }] }];



var test = function(els) {
  const newEls = []
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    if (els[i].age == 400) {
      console.log('found');
      console.log(els[i]);
    } else {
      newEls.push({
        age: els[i].age,
        els: test(els[i].els)
      })
    }
  }
  return newEls
}

console.log(tt) // -- show original array
const kk = test(tt); // -- show found item
console.log(kk); // -- show new array without the newly found item
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a recursive reduce for this. During your iteration you skip all item where `.age === 400`, before you return you do the same process for `.els`:

```js
const remove = xs =>
  xs.reduce((ret, {age, els}) =>
    age === 400
      ? ret
      : ret.concat({age, els: remove(els)}),
    []);


console.log(

  remove(data)
  
);
```

```html
<script>
const data = [
  {age: 4, els: [
    {age: 12, els: []},
    {age: 32, els: [
      {age: 44, els: []},
      {age: 100, els: [
        {age: 3, els: []},
        {age: 22, els: [
          {age: 13, els: []},
          {age: 99, els: []},
          {age: 88, els: [
            {age: 16, els: []}]}]}]}]}]},
  {age: 223, els: []},
  {age: 120, els: [
    {age: 300, els: []},
    {age: 301, els: [
      {age: 400, els: []}]}]}];
</script>
```